# Match the end of a block with Sweet.js

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

I'm trying to write a *case* macro in sweet.js but I don't know how to match the end of a block.
In particular I would like to match the code between the macro call and the end of the block that contains it.
For example if my macro is `myMacro`, and the code is as follows

```
var foo = function() {
    console.log('log1');
    myMacro(someArg);
    console.log('log2');
    console.log('log3');
}
```

I would like to be able to match the lines with 'log2' and 'log3'.
My guess is that I can't but I can't find a clear definition how matching works in the documentation (pointers would be appreciated).
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `...` pattern will match tokens to the end of a delimiter (or file if there is no delimiter) so you can do something like:

```
macro myMacro {
    rule { $x ... } => {
        function bar() {
            $x ...
        }
    }
}
```

This will just stick all the tokens following `myMacro` up to the closing delimiter inside of the `bar` function.

Comment: Ouch, I was sure I already tried this, I guess I was doing some other mistake. Thanks